# Why does list selection in a recursive lambda function throw recursion limit errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, lambda

Consider the two following recursive functions that calculate the factorial of an input that I naively thought would be the same:

1. `fact = lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x * fact(x-1)`
2. `fact = lambda x: [x*fact(x-1),1][x==0]`

The first runs fine but the second give me the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. This is true for for inputs where `x==0` and `x!=0`.

Why can't the lambda function handle the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. In the second variant *both* expressions in the list are evaluated, and only then the appropriate one is picked from it. But this does not stop the recursion from happening even when `x == 0`. And so the recursion continues into the negative numbers bumping into the memory limit.

`... if ... else ...` on the other hand will first evaluate the condition following the `if` keyword, and *only* evaluate the expression that corresponds to that result.